# Which queries require flush() in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, flush

This process, [flush](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/objectstate-flushing.html), occurs by default at the following points

- before some query executions
- from org.hibernate.Transaction.commit()
- from Session.flush()

The question is which queries require `flush()`?

Also I've noticed that when persisting an entity Hibernate generates `id` either before or after an `insert` statement depending on the `@id` generation strategy. It looks like Hibernate accesses a database before executing the `insert` statement to get an `id`. Does this also mean `flush()`? Or does `flush()` mean only one-directional synchronization - from Hibernate to DB?

Comment: flush() consists of writing the in-memory, pending changes to the database. It's executed before a query if Hibernate thinks that the result of the query might depend on the pending changes. For example, if you persist a new car, and then select all the cars, the new car must be written to the database otherwise the query won't find it as it should.

Comment: Thank you, but then
1. `flush()` doesn't mean `commit()`. If the level is read_commited, then how can the `select` see the new uncommited `car`?
2. In contrast, Hibernate could see it not from the uncommited changes but as it is the pending change, so can't grasp the whole process

Comment: This select sees the uncommitted car because it'sexecuted in the same transaction as the one which just inserted the car. isolation is between different transactions, not between statements of the same transaction. Hibernate does see it, but Hibernate to know if the where clause of the SQL query accepts the new car or not. Only the database can execute the SQL query.